# Problem with sending messages from server(PC) to client(Android) in JAVA chatting application

Tags: java, android, sockets, inputstream, serversocket

I'm trying to make a simple chat application between Server(PC) and Client(Android app). When I send message from Client to Server everything works fine and the message is displayed on the JFrame, but when I send messages from Server to Client, only the first messages works and arrives to the client, but not the following others.I think the problem is inside the run() method of the Thread class.

Here is the Client-side code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editText;
    TextView textView;
    Button button;
    private static Socket s;
    String message="";
    private static String ip="192.168.0.112";
    private static int port=3336;
    String messageReceived="";
    static DataInputStream in;
    static DataOutputStream out;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d("myTag", "App Started");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    }

    public void send(View v){
        message=editText.getText().toString();
        myTaskSend mt=new myTaskSend();
        mt.execute();
        editText.setText("");
    }

    public void connect(View v){
        myTaskConnect mt2=new myTaskConnect();
        mt2.execute();
    }

    class myTaskSend extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try{
                Log.d("myTag", "Message Sent: "+message);
                out.writeUTF(message);
                if(message.toLowerCase().equals("exit")){
                    Log.d("myTag", "Connection Closed");
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    class myTaskConnect extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try{

                s=new Socket(ip,port);
                Log.d("myTag", "Connection Successful");
                in=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                out=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                ReadThread t=new ReadThread();
                t.start();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    class ReadThread extends Thread{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            try{
                while(true){
                    messageReceived=in.readUTF();
                    Log.d("myTag", "Message Received: "+messageReceived);
                    textView.setText(textView.getText()+"Server: "+messageReceived+"\n");
                }

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Server-side code:

```
public class Server {
    
    static TextArea textArea;
    static TextField textField;
    static ServerSocket ss;
    static Socket s;
    static DataInputStream in;
    static DataOutputStream out;
    static int port=3336;
    private JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Server window = new Server();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        
        String msgin="";
        try {
            System.out.println("Starting the server...");
            ss=new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Server active on the port: "+port);
            s=ss.accept();
            System.out.println("Connection succesfull");
            ss.close();
            in=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            out=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("Waiting for a message from the client...");
            while(!msgin.toLowerCase().equals("exit")) {
                msgin=in.readUTF();
                textArea.setText(textArea.getText()+"Client: "+msgin+"\n");
                System.out.println("Message received");
            }
        
            s.close();
            System.out.println("Closing the connection");
            
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.err.println(e);
        }
        
    }
    
    public Server() {
        initialize();
    }
    
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame("SERVER");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 582, 451);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        textArea = new TextArea();
        textArea.setBounds(23, 10, 510, 239);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textArea);
        textField = new TextField();
        textField.setBounds(23, 319, 372, 49);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
        
        JButton button = new JButton("New button");
        frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(button);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    String msgout="";
                    msgout=textField.getText().trim();
                    out.writeUTF(msgout);
                    System.out.println("Message sent to the client: "+msgout);
                    textField.setText("");
                }catch(IOException e1) {
                    System.out.println(e1);
                }
            }
        });
        button.setBounds(425, 319, 108, 49);
        frame.getContentPane().add(button);
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Please try the method `out.flush();` after sending data to the client:

```
out.writeUTF(msgout);
out.flush();
System.out.println("Message sent to the client: "+msgout);
```

Comment: Thank you but your solution doesn't work. I'm pretty sure that the problem is inside the run() of the Thread class in che client-side.